# Ionic3 virtualScroll gives blank list when scrolling far ahead on large list

Tags: ionic-framework, scrolltop, virtualscroll

Using Ionic3 to implement large list scrolling with virtualScroll.
I added a vertical slider (input range) linked to a function using Ionic3

- **this.content.scrollTo(0, yVal, 1000)**

to scroll back and forth but if I scroll too far ahead in the list, I get the error

- **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollTop' of null**

I played with the time parameter but nothing seems to make a difference.
My list has 10k items and if I scroll one step at a time (1%), everything is fine. But if I try to go all the way to 50% of the list, I get a blank output with the above error.

What am I doing wrong ???

Live sample and code can be found here:

- https://ionic-list100k-segment-index.stackblitz.io
- https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-list100k-segment-index